# What is the fate of Spot's litter of kittens?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

My wife and I watched the episode [*Genesis*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Genesis_%28episode%29) a few nights ago.  In the episode, Picard and Data discovered that Spot's newborn kittens had not eaten in a day, due to Spot's devolution.  Picard and Data understandably had many things on their mind and positronic net at the time, respectively.  However, as animal lovers, we were surprised at their rather apathetic attitude towards helpless animals in distress.  Even with so much attention being placed on Data's cat for the majority of the episode, there is no end resolution concerning the kittens.

There are few sources which mention the kittens outside of their involvement in the cure to the virus, and as far as I can tell, they aren't referenced again in the few remaining episodes of the series.  Are there any canonical or non-canonical sources that give an explanation of their fate?  Did they survive long enough for Spot to nurse them back to health after her re-evolution?

Comment: I thought he was locked in stasis as everyone died of radiation poisoning and then they evolved into a sentient race of cat people....wrong show?

Comment: You have opened the door to a new realm of fan fiction. This universe isn't big enough for Robert Picardo and Chris Barrie to exist side-by-side.

Comment: "However, as animal lovers, we were surprised at their rather apathetic attitude towards helpless animals in distress."... something tells me Picard & Data had a lot more on their minds at the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I don't think there are any internet references available on this subject.**

After examining almost a dozen sources on the subject of [Spot](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Spot) and his/her kittens and finding no mention of their fate, one leans toward the conclusion that there is no data on the internet available about the fictional or nonfictional fate of Spot's kittens.  I've read a few TNG related books and can recall no mention of Spot's kittens' fate.  Ultimately it maybe that no one cared enough to record their fate.

One would assume that Spot's kittens survived, if Spot herself couldn't nurse them, then they could have the school kids nurse-feed them or use some form of technology.